# Modal Window: How can I set a different content for each modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on my own custom modal window, but I've a problem. I'd like to create multiple modal window, but I need to apply a different content for each.

My HTML code:

```
        <div id="footer">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a class="modal-window-trigger" id="help" href="help.php">Help</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="modal-window-trigger" id="faq" href="faq.php">Frequently Asked Questions</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <span id="footer-copyright">
                    <a href="./..">Coded by Dylan - ©2015-2016</a>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-window">
            <div class="modal-window-container">
                <span class="modal-window-closer" title="Close the overlay"></span>
                <h1 class="big-title" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">First Modal Window</h1>
                <p>First Modal Window Text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-window">
            <div class="modal-window-container">
                <span class="modal-window-closer" title="Close the overlay"></span>
                <h1 class="big-title" style="margin-bottom: 15px;">Second Modal Window</h1>
                <p>Second Modal Window Text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="expose-mask"></div>
```

My JavaScript code:

```
(function($)
{
    $(".modal-window-trigger").click(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".modal-window").addClass("shown");
        $("#expose-mask").css({"visibility": "visible"});
    });
    $(".modal-window-closer, #expose-mask").click(function(){
        $("#expose-mask").css({"visibility": "hidden"});
        $(".modal-window").removeClass("shown");
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Result: http://prntscr.com/7gd7g6

I'd like to show the specific content when I click on the "Help" text and another content when I click on the "Frequently Asked Questions" text.

How can I set an unique data for each modal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    (function($)
        {
            $(".modal-window-trigger").click(function(e)
            {
                e.preventDefault();
                var modal_id = $(this).attr('name');
                show_modal(modal_id)

            });
            $(".modal-window-closer, #expose-mask").click(function(){
                $("#expose-mask").css({"visibility": "hidden"});
                $(".modal-window").removeClass("shown");
            });
        })(jQuery);

        function show_modal(modal_id){      
            $('#'+modal_id).addClass("shown");
            $("#expose-mask").css({"visibility": "visible"});  
        }
```

add name attribute for `<a class="modal-window-trigger" name="model1">` and change id the modal-window to model1 respectivily.

Comment: Thanks. Still have a problem. It is possible to add my class "modal-window" to style all modal window? Because I can see in your code that it has disappeared and I need to stylize all modal windows. http://prntscr.com/7gef1n

Comment: you can add additional class for style

Comment: Thanks for your help. :) Worked!

Answer (score 1):

```
    (function($)
    {
        $(".modal-window-trigger").click(function(e)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            var attrid = $(this).attr('id');
            if(attrid=='help'){
                $(".modal-window1").addClass("shown");
                $("#expose-mask").css({"visibility": "visible"});
                return;
            }else if(attrid=='faq'){
                $(".modal-window2").addClass("shown");
                $("#expose-mask").css({"visibility": "visible"});
                return;     
            }
        });
        $(".modal-window-closer, #expose-mask").click(function(){
            $("#expose-mask").css({"visibility": "hidden"});
            $(".modal-window").removeClass("shown");
        });
    })(jQuery);
```

change the class modal-window to modal-window1 for first window and modal-window to modal-window2 for second window

Comment: Thanks for that, but is it possible to have a code to not grow when adding other modal windows? I intend to add at least 10 modal windows and it's going to be a long code.

Comment: is that dynamic content?

Comment: Something like that: http://web.enavu.com/tutorials/how-to-make-a-completely-reusable-jquery-modal-window/ example, "name" is linked to the data http://prntscr.com/7gebn3

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same question while creating a web app with React.
First, I created a react component call GeneralModal. In the first div tag I assigned id={props.id} so that every time I want to pass in new content into the modal framework, I create a new id for the modal without having to duplicate the code. Like this:

```
<div class="modal fade" id={props.id} tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

Then, at where I want to pass in new content (modal's body), I used

```
<div class="modal-body">
   {props.children}
</div>
```

In the component I want to call the modal, I write:

```
<BackdropModal children={<About/>} id={"about"} next={false} title={"About Peacock"}/>
```

Here I am assigning an id to the general modal with content  so that this id is uniquely associated with the specific content

Then, I use this button to call modal with this specific content:

```
<a class="nav-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#about" href="#about">About</a>
```